# How to deal with getting credit for something you didn't do?

Tags: internship, team, politics

So I'm working on a project, and was told to work with a partner for a specific part of it. Basically, I supplied the data/explained the project and then my Partner did the remaining work as it's something I don't have an expertise in.

My PM has recently been out of town for a couple weeks. However, coming back from vacation the PM wasn't aware of who is working on what and he gave us equal credit for finishing the task-- which I didn't expect, and I dont think is fair.

I've since spoken to my partner and let him know that I was surprised by the equal recognition, as he did most of the work. He basically said " I don't mind sharing the credit", but it seems dishonest to take equal credit?

Am I just making too big of a deal of this/should let things stand? The PM specifically sent an email thanking us both for getting it done as well (as well as an official company recognition that comes with $25).... should I just drop a email back saying, "Hey thanks, but Partner did the heavy lifting" ?

Comment: Don't worry about it - next time something goes wrong, you'll share equal blame :)

Comment: @LaconicDroid haha good way to think of it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is probably nice to put something into writing in form of a thank you email with your partner and manager copied in where you can say something like:

"Thank you for the recognition on the completion of this task.  As the vast majority of work was completed by X I would like to personally thank him as well."

Or something along those lines.

It is a tactful way to make sure he is recognized and might avoid resentment from your partner as well as making you look dishonest if/when your manager finds out who completed the task.